# Changeable desktop pictures

Tags: macos

In changeable desktop pictures I use the pictures in iPhoto. Occasionally there shows a picture that I'd like to see in iPhoto. Is there a way to get the picture info while it shows as the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you can't. Your desktop just uses your iPhoto library to generate the background randomly.
So, the shown background is just a one-way link to the picture in your iPhoto library.